# X-Forwarded-For causing 502 error for asp.net core 1.1 deployed on IIS

Tags: iis, proxy, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We are hosting an ASP.NET Core 1.1 website on Windows 2008 R2 server with IIS7.5. We got some error reports that users of the website that were using a web proxy got 502's. So by setting up an out of the box installation of a Squid proxy I can successfully reproduce the issue that they are experiencing.

---

This works just fine all day, every day:

**Client** -> **Web proxy** -> **IIS** -> **Kestrel**

---

This fails *every time* with "502 - web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server":

**Client** -> **Web proxy** -> *Load Balancer* -> **IIS** -> **Kestrel**

---

Using Microsoft's Message Analyzer I got the request headers sent from both the load balancer and the web proxy.
The one that works only has *one* IP number in the X-Forwarded-For reqeust header, whereas the one that fails has *two*.

`X-Forwarded-For: <Client_IP>` vs. `X-Forwarded-For: <Client_IP>, <Proxy_IP>`

Is there something that I don't get? Am I supposed to do some magic configuration of the IIS or is this a bug in the IISIntegration? This works just fine if I have the same setup and run a plain old ASP.NET website.

I found a a workaround using the URL Rewrite Module, but it doesn't feel right:

```
<rule name="Clear">
     <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
     <serverVariables>
         <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" value="0.0.0.0" replace="true"/>
     </serverVariables>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Sounds like an exception in the application. Have you turned on logging to see what's happening?

Comment: Yes, the stdout doesn't register a thing when the client hits 502.

Comment: So key is: DotNetCore.1.1.0-WindowsHosting, Microsoft-IIS/7.5 and a , in the X-Forwarded-For header.

Comment: Is this rule for your APIs Web.config?  I host an API and have a client using Squid and they are seeing a 502 as well.  Did the rule work for you?

Comment: @franzke Yep. Works fine for me.